M3: Usage of Body.Small typography token in input fields?
Looking at the documentation for Material 3 and the implementation of the token on the Text Field component. https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/specs
Its stated that the "label". (The text above the input field) is md.sys.typescale.body-small and the same for the "supporting text" (The text under the input field to give context or show faults) is also md.sys.typescale.body-small.
(They are labeled as 4 and 9 on the m3 text-fields documentation spec page)
Looking at the documentation in general and the structure of the typography token, in my opinion, it should reference md.sys.typescale.label-small or md.sys.typescale.label-medium as that seams  that would be a more accurate implementation and usage of the typography. But perhaps I misunderstand something here? It seams awkward to me at least that a body variant is used here.
https://m3.material.io/styles/typography/type-scale-tokens
